Tkinter Plot becomes blurry when in a frame
TEST_PLOT.py
[![import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

class TestPlot:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.create_plot()

    def create_plot(self):
        # Generate x values
        x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)

        # Compute y values
        y = x**2

        # Create the plot
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
        self.ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = x^2$')
        self.ax.set_title('Plot of $y = x^2$')
        self.ax.set_xlabel('x')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('y')
        self.ax.legend()
        self.ax.grid(True)

        if self.master:
            # Embed the plot in the Tkinter frame
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.master)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
            self.canvas.draw()
        else:
            # Show the plot standalone
            plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    


All nice and sharp.
But when I utilise this script in a frame it becomes slightly fuzzy:
test1.py
import tkinter as tk
from TEST_PLOT import TestPlot  # Assuming the above code is saved in test_plot.py

class Test1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.title('Test1 - Main Window with Plot')
        self.geometry('800x600')

        # Create a single frame for the plot
        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='lightblue', bd=5, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Embed TestPlot within the frame
        test_plot = TestPlot(frame)
        test_plot.master.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Test1()
    app.mainloop()


Sure it's some compression issue but not sure what is the best way to resolve.
Would like to use Tkinter as default with Python. Though I am open to better graphic options.
When I use this in my actual program there's also something very odd happening in that the Tkinter icon itself becomes blurry..



Can you show the full images of the GUI, I mean full comparison of both blurry and clear GUI

I tried it on my PC (Windows) and it seemed to work just fine (it was "nice and sharp"). Even though I have only the default tkinter icon, it didn't seem blurry. What are you versions of tkinter and matplotlib ?

@Lrx The issue is for sure with DPI, I have same problems before too

still looking into this. result appears somewhat randomly with different scripts. Initially though it was an issue being on multiple screens (indeed, loads sharper when dragged to a different screen) but now just working standalone on laptop (macOS) and some scripts load clear, others blurry
